# How to get all cells that appear more than 5 times?

Tags: openoffice-calc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWEfu.png)

I have a table in OpenOffice that contains a column with region's codes (column J). Using table functions, how to get all codes that appear more than 5 times and write them in one cell?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ike yes, i wrote a function that returns 1 if code appears more than 5 times: IF(COUNTIF(исходник.J2:J552;исходник.A2:J552)>5;1;0).
But i dont know how to put code into array and then put array into one cell.

Comment: Your comment is important. It would be better to edit the question to include that information. Also, it is better to give a simplified example in text instead of an image, and tell the desired result. That way people can answer the question more easily, and others can learn from this post if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would recommend breaking this problem down into smaller parts using helper columns. Or better yet, move the data into LibreOffice Base which can easily work with distinct values.

However, I managed to come up with a rather large formula that seems to do what you asked. Enter it as an [array formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html).

```
=TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF(COUNTIF(исходник.J$2:J$552;исходник.J2:J552)>5;IF(ROW(исходник.J2:J552)=MATCH(исходник.J2:J552;исходник.J$2:J$552;0)+ROW(J$2)-1;исходник.J2:J552;"")))
```

I can't test this on your actual data since your example is only an image, but let's say that there are six of both 77 and 37. Then this would show `77,37` as the result.

Here is a breakdown. Look up the functions in LibreOffice Online Help for more information.

- `=TEXTJOIN(",";1;` — Join all results into a single cell, separated by commas.
- `IF(COUNTIF(исходник.J$2:J$552;исходник.J2:J552)>5;` — Find codes that occur more than 5 times. This is the same as what you wrote.
- `IF(ROW(исходник.J2:J552)=` — Compare the next result to the row number that we are currently looking at.
- `MATCH(исходник.J2:J552;исходник.J$2:J$552;0)+ROW(J$2)-1;` — Determine the first row that has this code. We do this to get unique results instead of 6 or more of each code in the result.
- `исходник.J2:J552;"")))` —  Return the code. (Your formula simply returns 1 here, which doesn't seem to be what you want.) If it doesn't match, return an empty string rather than 0, because `TEXTJOIN` ignores empty strings.